# How to convert a image to base64 React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

can you suggest me the best way with any library or something else to convert this image to base64:
[image]

The first time I thought the atributte `data` is base64, but I used this funtcion:

```
function isBase64(str) {
if (str ==='' || str.trim() ===''){ return false; }
try {
    return btoa(atob(str)) == str;
} catch (err) {
    return false;
}}
```

so, when I introduce the attribute `data` this function return me `false`

Comment: Looks like it's already base64, which isn't great because this is a waste of storage, bandwidth, CPU, and memory.  There is very rarely an actual reason to use base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like it. You can copy below code, and use these methods.

```
const chars =
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

const Base64 = {
  btoa: (input = '') => {
    let str = input;
    let output = '';

    for (
      let block = 0, charCode, i = 0, map = chars;
      str.charAt(i | 0) || ((map = '='), i % 1);
      output += map.charAt(63 & (block >> (8 - (i % 1) * 8)))
    ) {
      charCode = str.charCodeAt((i += 3 / 4));

      if (charCode > 0xff) {
        throw new Error(
          "'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.",
        );
      }

      block = (block << 8) | charCode;
    }

    return output;
  },

  atob: (input = '') => {
    let str = input.replace(/[=]+$/, '');
    let output = '';

    if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.",
      );
    }
    for (
      let bc = 0, bs = 0, buffer, i = 0;
      (buffer = str.charAt(i++));
      ~buffer && ((bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer), bc++ % 4)
        ? (output += String.fromCharCode(255 & (bs >> ((-2 * bc) & 6))))
        : 0
    ) {
      buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
    }

    return output;
  },
};

export default Base64;
```